# Why does request.ParseForm() drain the request.Body?

Tags: go, http-request

In this code, if I comment the `ParseForm()` invocation the request works as expected

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    v := make(url.Values)
    v.Set("status", "yeah!")
    request, error := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://httpbin.org/post", strings.NewReader(v.Encode()))
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
    }

    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    err:=request.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)    
    }
    fmt.Println(request.Form["status"])

    response, error := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(response)
    }
}
```

But if I call ParseForm() the body is cleared and I get:

```
Post http://httpbin.org/post: http: Request.ContentLength=14 with Body length 0
```

Is like the Body length has been drained. How can I access the form values? I need to create a signature of the request. Is there other way (other than creating the signature directly from the parameters directly? )

Answer (score 1):

Use **ParseForm** for read the request, not set.
For simple POST you can do:

```
resp, err := http.PostForm("http://example.com/form", url.Values{"key": {"Value"}, "id": {"123"}})
```

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Post
http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#PostForm

Comment: I need to modify the headers to add a custom one, is there a way to do that with the mentioned methods? How else can I read the form values in the request?

Comment: I think you allready know the form value when you making the request?

Comment: Not really, I was working on a function to add a signature to an http request: `funct Sign(r *http.Request)`  I guess I would need to keep the r.Body in a variable and set it back again.

Comment: Can you sign your request by the Header rather than request Body?

Comment: Yeah, but the signature is created based on the request parameters, either from the query string or ( in the case of the post method ) from the body parameters.

Comment: Body is a reade (it like a stream). By the line #2 you assigned *body* to *postRequest.Body*. *ParseForm* read all the Body (normally you just use that method in your server's handler function for reading incomming request). We should have a little chat about this!

Comment: yes, we do :) actually the way it is there didn't work either.